# Binding Intellisense not working for some controls with inherited DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, intellisense, datacontext

I set my window's `DataContext` to my ViewModel within XAML.

When I now want to create a binding for a property on some control, I normally have working Intellisense (showing my ViewModel's properties). In the following example, this works for `Grid` and `TabControl`. Yet, on `TabItem`, Intellisense is not working anymore.

Bindings themself work without problems, just Intellisense is not working.

Here my example code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="My App" Height="768" Width="1024">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel></vm:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid> <!-- Intellisense works here -->
        <TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl"> <!-- Intellisense works here too -->
            <TabItem Header="{Binding Heading}"> <!-- Intellisense DOES NOT work here -->
              ...
```